# gcov generates empty coverage for c

Tags: c, linux, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I'm trying to collect code coverage for the project that has c++ and c code both on Ubuntu.

I use '-fprofile-arcs' and '-ftest-coverage' values as CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS; '-lgcov' as LINKFLAGS.

Common C project structure is:

```
c_code\
     src
     unit_tests
```

src contains sources of static library.

unit_tests dir contain tests written with googletest framework e. g. tests of kind

```
TEST_F(test_case_name, test_name) {
    some_gtest_assertions;
}
```

After the build googletest binary that should contain static library to test inside of it is launched.

Building and running of the project binaries results in generating of *.gcno and *.gcda files. However my C coverage results are empty (C++ is generated well).

lcov command has the folloiwng format:

```
lcov --capture --directory my_c_gcda_location --output-file c_coverage.info
```

Logs of lcov show the following for C-related gcda files:

> gcov did not create any files for "my_c_gcda_location/*.gcda"`

There are also errors of kind:

> *.gcda:stamp mismatch with notes file

Should I specify some additional parameters or perform some additional actions to get coverage results for C? Or what can be the reason of these issues?

Comment: You will have to provide the `minimum verifiable code` showing how `my_c_gcda_location` does file handling/creation -- or nobody can do anything but guess. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may get "stamp mismatch" when the .gcda files are newer than the .gcno files.

It can happen mostly for 2 reasons:
1. You might have re-build the code after running the test and before trace file generation.
2. The binary might be built in one machine and test was ran in other machine, whose time is ahead of the build machine.

For these two cases you have to just make sure the file creation time of .gcda is greater than .gcno and .c* files.

You can do that by just doing "touch *.gcda" and then run the lcov command.

Comment: Finally I find out place where the second rebuild was triggered (static and shared libraries were built both). Switching off building of shared libraries (as coverage on static was enough for my purposes) resolved the issue

Comment: touch doesn't work, looks like the timestamp is in the actual file contents (vs. an inode timestamp). i.e. `hexdump -e '"%x\n"' -s8 -n4 myclass.gcda`. See http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/code-coverage-with-gcov - Troubleshooting.